# Yii, Update CGridView dataprovider based on AJAX result

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm not sure that I am going about this the right way but here goes.

I have a dropdown list, when I change the values of this list I wish to update the dataprovider of a CGridView via Ajax.

dropDownList

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,
    'assigned_to', 
    CHtml::listData(Users::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username'),
    array(
        'empty' => 'Please Select',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('CrmCalendar/Create', array('id'=>$model->model_id,'modelId'=>$model->model, 'updateGrid'=>1)),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'success'=>'function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update("user-activites-grid", {
                        data: data
                    });     
            }',
        ),
    )
); ?>
```

CGridView Widget

```
<?php $this::widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-activites-grid',
    'ajaxUpdate' => true,
    'dataProvider'=>$model->dpUserActivities(),
    ));
?>
```

Controller Action

```
public function actiongetUserActivitesUpdate($id, $modelId)
{
    $model=new CrmCalendar;
    $model->model = $modelId;
    $model->model_id = $id; 
    if(isset($_GET['updateGrid']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['CrmCalendar'];
        $newDp = $model->dpUserActivities();
        echo serialize($newDp);
    }
}
```

dpUserActivities

```
public function dpUserActivities($size=20)
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $this->StartTime);
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>array('condition'=>'assigned_to=:assigned_to AND DATE(StartTime) = :date', 'params'=>array(':assigned_to'=>$this->assigned_to, ':date'=>$date),),   
        'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>$size,),
        'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'Starttime ASC',),
    ));
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when the drop down for assigned to is changed then the the value is stored back into the $model and the dpUserActivites is re run with the new data and then the CGridView is updated.

Sorry if this makes no sense.

Let me know if you need any more information

Regards.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, would using SESSION be a vaild way forward, store user in SESSION, the use that variable in the dpUserActivites and then refresh the grid??

Comment: Have you seen how search works in CRUD standard actions? For example, in any generated crud, admin view, you have "Advanced Search" form that make just you are looking for

Comment: Hiya All, thanks for you replies, I finally used a render_partial and an ajax success to re do the HTML in the render